# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (256,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I get some errors when I run the code in [this tutorial](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/keras/text_classification). I want to predict on some test data. When I run the following it works:

```
res = model.predict(test_data[0:2], verbose=1)   # this works
[[0.25896776]
 [0.9984256 ]]
```

However, when I run the following piece of code:

```
res = model.predict(test_data[0], verbose=1)     # this does not work
```

It gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (256,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktrB9.png) is the `test_data[0]` shape and details. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking your next question, please take some time and read the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to understand how you should format your question. You might get some ideas from the edits I made. And please please please **don't** post the errors or any code **as an image**. Instead, post them as text in code blocks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use `test_data[0:1]` instead of `test_data[0]`.

**Long answer:** The Keras/TF models works on **batch** of input samples. Therefore, when you give them only one input sample, it should still have a shape of `(1, sample_shape)`. However, when you slice the `test_data` array like `test_data[0]` it would give you the first element with the first axis/dimension removed, i.e. with the shape of `(sample_shape,)` (in this case `(256,)`). To resolve this, use `test_data[0:1]` in order to preserve the first axis/dimension (i.e. shape would be `(1, 256)`).